# Rreading asp.net web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a web api which returns product lists and price. The product list is displayed on page using Ajax.

The prices gets updates regularly.

The only way i know how to tackle problem is to continuously call the API and check if price has been updated using a javascript loop.

Is there any other way such as adding a listener which tracker when the price are updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve it through a regular JavaScript Ajax-call is to call the API from time to time, to see if the data has changed. A polling-approach. This often works well if updates once every minute or so is sufficient, but it can become rather traffic intense if you want close to real time updates.

There are other ways to achieve instant updates, that doesn't require polling though. One option suitable for .Net, that has been talked a lot about lately, is [SinalR](http://signalr.net/). SignalR uses [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) in modern browsers that support it, and fall back to use other technologies in older browsers.

Comment: I was gonna use signalR but i don't have access to the web api code to implement SignalR. I guess polling is the best way then.

Comment: @RajuKumar Yeah, without backend access, I believe continuous polling is your best shot.

Answer (score 1):

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it
>   incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your
>   applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability
>   to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as
>   it happens, in real-time.